# Whether $2^{38}$ or $3^{33}$ is greater without needing a calculator

Tags: discrete-mathematics

My question is about figuring out whether $2^{38}$ or  $3^{33}$ is greater without needing a calculator, by using the Mobius function or by other means?

Comment: These numbers aren't particularly close.  Hint:  $2^3<3^2$.

Comment: @lulu Thank you, I wouldn't have thought that it can be seen so easily :)

Comment: @lulu Great hint +1

Comment: @Peter  Well, I wonder if the OP meant something else.  $3^{38}$ is more nearly $2^{52}$.  Though the same hint works there as well.

Comment: @lulu Do I miss something ? I see no relationship between the Mobius function and to compare the magnitude of powers ...

Comment: @Peter  Oh, I agree with you.  I don't see any way to use the Mobius function to handle problems like this.  I always proceed as with my hint...look for useful near-equalities.  Helps if you know, or strongly suspect, the answer.

Comment: @lullu brillant simple idea...I wish math was always as elegant as this

Comment: Similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276227/how-would-you-prove-that-250-333-without-directly-calculating-the-valu

Comment: Two similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1788290, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1676066. Closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1943588.

Answer (score 11):

Using lulu's hint , we have $$2^{38}<2^{39}=(2^3)^{13}<(3^2)^{13}=3^{26}<3^{33}$$

Comment: Brilliant ! (+1)

Comment: Or $3^{33} > 3^{32} = (3^2)^{16} > (2^3)^{16} = 2^{48} > 2^{38}$.

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty with problems like this is that the smaller base has the larger exponent, which makes it hard to immediately see which is really smaller.  Hence the trick is to find an easier to understand inequality, then raise each side to a common power, making it more clear what is *really* going on.  In this case, the helpful hint suggests that $8 = 2^3 < 3^2 = 9$.  From this, we get
$$ 2^3 < 3^2 \implies (2^3)^{13} < (3^2)^{13} \implies 2^{39} < 3^{26}. $$
It hopefully clear that $2^{38} < 2^{39}$ and that $3^{26} < 3^{33}$, from which the desired result is obtained.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another answer: we have $2^{38}=2^{33}2^5$, and $3^{33}=(2\cdot {3\over 2})^{33}=2^{33}({3\over 2})^{33}$, so we just need to compare $2^5$ and $({3\over 2})^{33}$. Now $({3\over 2})^2={9\over 4}>2$, so $$({3\over 2})^{33}>(({3\over 2})^2)^{16}>2^{16}>2^5.$$

Answer (score 1):

Binomial theorem:

$$3^{33} = (2 + 1)^{33} = 2^{33} + 31 \times 2^{32} + \binom{33}{31}2^{31} + \dots > \binom{33}{31}2^{31} = \frac{33\times 32}{2}\times2^{31}$$
$$> 32 \times 16\times 2^{31} = 2^{40} > 2^{38}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since$$3^{33}>2^{38}\iff\log_2(3^{33})>\log_2(2^{38})\iff\log_2(3)>\frac{38}{33}$$you will just have to prove that $\log_2(3)>\frac{38}{33}$. But $\sqrt2<\frac32$. Therefore $2^{\frac32}<3$ and this is equivalent to $\frac32<\log_23$ and so$$\log_23>\frac32>\frac{38}{33}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $2^{11} \approx 3^{7} \approx 2000$, you can estimate it:

$$\begin{array} {rcl}
2^{38} & \text{vs} & 3^{33} 
\\
\left( 2^{11} \right)^{38/11} & \text{vs} & \left( 3^{7} \right)^{33/7}
\\
\frac{38}{11} & \text{vs} & \frac{33}{7}
\\
38 \times 7 & \text{vs} & 33 \times 11
\\
266 & < & 343
\end{array}$$

$38/11$ being close to a small integer is why the approximation is close enough.